# would really like some help. I have searched through several other questions but could not find anything wrong in my CREATE statement

Tags: mysql-5.7

```
CREATE TABLE crime1(
  ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  Case VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Dated timestamp NOT NULL,
  Block VARRCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  Iucr VARCHAR(10),
  Prime CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  Description VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  Beat INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  District INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  District INT,
  Last_Updated timestamp,
  Year timestamp default now(),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Case VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>   Dated timestamp NOT NULL,
>   Block VARRCHAR(30) NOT NULL' at line 3

Comment: Learn what the reserved words are in your DBMS. They're listed in the documentation.

Comment: if you want to use a reserved word as a name, `backquote it.

Answer (score 2):

CASE is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) you will need to quote it instead:

```html
`Case`
```

While you can quote it as a workaround, you should avoid using reserved words as column and/or table names.

Also this

`Block VARRCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,`

Should probably be:

`Block VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,`

Note that BLOCK is also a reserved word, so you will likely need to quote it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rename Case to something else as far as it's reserved in SQL

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARRCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
Iucr VARCHAR(10),
Prime CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Desc' at line 5

Comment: Thanks to @Sean, BLOCK is reserved word too

Comment: Double RR in VARCHAR agains Block?